# Django model inheritance: override restrictions in child classes

Tags: python, django, inheritance, model

I will try to abstract my problem:

I need to create two model classes for IPv4 and IPv6.
I want to do it via inheritance; namely, to create a model class, and then to inherit from this class, but with the additional (different) limit for each of the child classes:

```
class IP(models.Model):
    ip = models.GenericIPAddressField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class IPv4(IP):
    ip = models.GenericIPAddressField(protocol='ipv4')


class IPv6(IP):
    ip = models.GenericIPAddressField(protocol='ipv6')
```

I'm not sure whether or not this is the correct way to do that, and I would like to know which problems might be caused due to such a model.

Comment: Try and see what happens. If it works then it's good :D

Comment: IMHO I think you don't even need the field in the abstract class anyway.

Comment: Does your real base `IP` model have anything more than what you posted ? I assume that it's case, else having a base class seems quite useless ;-)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers It has. This is an abstract example.

Comment: @BogdanIulianBursuc It works. But I don't know whether this is something that might cause problems that I miss. E.g., problems with the DB. And maybe, there is a better way to do it. Toy example won't help me. I try to avoid future problems (that I don't know what are they).

Answer (score 0):

The Abstract Model is usually used to define a model with common fields.
If you define the same field in two models, that field is unnecessary for the base model.
However, in your code, that field('IP.ip') will be virtually absent, so it will not be an operational problem.